# Do I need to put commas around "in general"?

Tags: commas

Based on the following phrase:

> Comparing to the state of the art that uses, in general, more than
>   one variable to perform...

Is this correct to put the "in general" between commas?

Comment: It's not incorrect, but neither is it correct! It certainly makes the phrase much easier to understand, but there really are very few genuine "rules" regaring the comma. (_Compared to_ is much better than the gerund-participle here.)

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand your point. If it is not incorrect and makes the phrase easier to understand it seems to be a 'good choice', doesn't it? Do you have any other suggestion? Anyway, thanks for the tip.

Comment: @KelvinS - Is it a good choice? Is it correct? It’s important to understand those are two **different** questions. By the way, have you tried to Google `“When to use a comma”` or `“Rules for comma usage”`?

Comment: A example of an _incorrect_ usage in English is: _"She **are** beautiful and brilliant too."_ There is a _rule_ in English that requires agreement in number between subject and verb. Where the comma is concerned, though, we can write _"She is beautiful, and brilliant too"_, or _"She is beautiful and brilliant too"_, or _"She is beautiful, and brilliant, too"_ and none of them would be "correct" or "incorrect". There are useful _guidelines_ for usage of the comma, but none of them are "rules". In general, we place the comma where we would pause in speech.

Comment: In fairness, I think there are plenty of *de facto* rules on comma usage that exist because a wide variety of style guides agree on them. And putting a comma where you'd pause in speech is not one of those, by the way.

Comment: @cjl750 I hope I didn't characterize the observation that we place the comma where we would pause in speech as a "rule"! True, most style guides agree on some principles of comma placement, and there are instances in which a comma is necessary to the sense of a sentence, but there are no rules governing the comma in the sense that agreement in number is a rule. This is important for learners to grasp: they should not be led to believe that _"She is beautiful and brillant too"_ violates a "rule" that "requires" a comma before _too_.

Comment: @P.E.Dant I agree with you completely that nothing about commas is as close to a rule as number agreement is. I just seem to see a lot of answers/comments around the site that mention that there's no hard and fast rules on X but fail to mention what are by now pretty firm guidelines. I am afraid that that leads learners too far in the opposite direction (in this case, that commas are basically made up and we shouldn't really worry about them much). Just want to strike a nice middle ground :)

Comment: @cjl750 That's exactly the ground I try to strike. Many learners are victims of "teachers" who tell them: _"**Too** at the end of a sentence must always be separated by a comma from the clause"_, or some such rubbish.

Answer (score 0):

That is a good use of commas. It sets off the parathetical phrase "in general" from the rest of the sentence. Round brackets "()" could also be used, to set off the phrase even further. But brackets are not required and would feel to "heavy" for such a short intrusion.

The rest of the sentence has some problems — You could use "compared to" not "comparing". "State of the art" is a abstract noun, so its unclear how it "uses" something, I'd interpret that as "state of the art things use..." but I'm missing some context here.

Comment: I believe that the ellipsis represents that part of the original sentence is omitted. Are any of your doubts about the "sentence" alleviated by the possibility of more clauses?

Comment: @epl I'd assume that too, but I would still have problems with "state of the art uses" and The use of "comparing seems incorrect.

Comment: *...many time-sensitive operations, the older system offers little advantage, even considering its lower cost.*